# как вставить новые данные в products_id где user_id = n

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]нужно,что бы добавлялись новые id продукта у определенного пользователя

Comment: Переделать структуру БД. добавить отдельную таблицу в которой будет  user_id (или id из текущей таблицы) и product_id. По одному id продукта на запись. тогда добавлять можно будет штатными средствами, просто вставкой новой записи. БД не предназначены для работы с данными через запятую. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <table> SET products_id=CONCAT_WS(',',products_id,<new_product_id>) WHERE user_id=<user_id>
```